# Why so many keystrokes to duplicate a word with an edit in between them?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Let's say I want to edit the text

```
blahblah WombatModeFunctor
```

to be

```
blahblah WombatModeFunctor::WombatModeFunctor
```

The way I know to do it is:

1. Move the caret (cursor) until it is over the W
2. Use `yw` to yank the word
3. **Move the caret 1 position to the left of the W**
4. Use `p` to paste the yanked word.  Now you have:

   `blahblah WombatModeFunctorWombatModeFunctor`

but the caret is over the first 'r', so you have to

5. **Move the caret 1 position to the right of the r**
6. Enter INSERT mode
7. Type `::`

My questions are:

- Why is step 3 necessary?  It seems silly that a `p` right after a `yw` would cause a pasting after the first letter of the word you just yanked.
- Why is step 5 necessary? It seems more intuitive that the caret would be after the final pasted character, not on top of it
- Is there a more efficient vim incantation for this action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Step 3 is not necessary, you can use `P` instead of `p`.
2. Step 5 is not necessary, you can use `a` instead of `i` to enter insert mode.

---

An alternative approach is this, assuming cursor is on the first `W`:

```
C<c-r>"::<c-r>"
```

Here `C` will delete the text from the cursor to the end of line, then enter insert mode and `<c-r>"` (from insert mode) will paste the content of the last used register.

Comment: Thanks.  I would have expected `p` to behave as `P` and `i` to behave as `a`, since the behavior I wanted seems like the more-common need.  (Indeed, I cannot think of any case where I would want the behavior of `p`.)

Comment: Actually, these are minor but important differences. I use both `i`, `a`, `p` and `P` often. It is all about understanding the different commands and when to apply them. `i` and `P` acts in front of normal mode cursor, while `a` and `p` acts after. Both behaviours are useful in different scenarios.

Comment: @RyanV.Bissell You'll probably want `p` if you want to paste after the end of the line...

Answer (score 2):

With caret at the beginning of the line: `wy$Pa::`

Comment: Very nice!   It's clear that I should spend more time thinking about how to economize my vim incantations.

Comment: If you want to be even more economic, you might consider mapping `Y` to `y$`. This provides a nice analog to `D` and is often useful. It's old functionality will still be available to you via `yy` (which normally duplicates `Y`).

Comment: Totally agree @Octaviour, I use `Y` a lot. I also enjoy the extra eye-candy of [haya14busa/vim-operator-flashy](https://github.com/haya14busa/vim-operator-flashy)'s plugin, makes yanking feel better.